# How does Gmail API quota work at user level?

Tags: gmail-api, rate-limiting

I've searched for this topic, but I haven't found a good explanation of the **moving average** part.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota explains how Gmail quota works. It says the following

> 250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts)

Gmail API **message.get** costs 5 quotas. Does that mean that I can only make 50 (250/5) **message.get** requests per second?

How does `moving average` work with the rate limit and when does it allow short bursts?

Comment: This means the per second limit can be overcome for short periods of time, but you will get an error if this rhythm is sustained over time. The exact details of this, though, are not documented (how much time, how many quota units would be accepted for this short time, etc.). Therefore, in order to make sure no error comes up, I'd suggest not to go beyond 250 per user per second at any time. Does this answer your question? If that's the case, I'd post this as an answer.